# Android. Prompt access device's location

Tags: android, android-gps

In my old Android (Samsung S3 mini) It wasn't necessary to make anything to allow my app to use the location (GPS) of my phone.
Now I am using an LG G4 with Android 6.0 and it is not using the GPS ever.
I can see that in apps like waze, there is a prompt "Allow Waze to access this device's location?".  I guess I have to do something similar to trigger this option before start my app.
Anyone know how to do that. I have no idea how to ask Google.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an excellent demo https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On android 6.0 you have to request some permissions at Runtime. It's explain here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

For request permissions at runtime you should do something like this(before you want to use GPS) :

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Check Permissions Now
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 2;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        // Display UI and wait for user interaction
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
              this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.LOCATION_FINE},
    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
} else {
    // permission has been granted, continue as usual
    Location myLocation =
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

You have an example for GPS here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions